# Select contiguous values numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have two numpy arrays

```
array1 = np.array([1,2,3,10,11,12,13,14,15,16])

array2 = np.array([1,2,10,11,12,13,14,15])
```

The values of each array are contiguous except the first values due to a noise in the measurements

What is the best way to remove noisy values?

Comment: The logic is unclear, do you need the two arrays as input? Can you provide some more examples, making sure to also give the matching expected output for each pair of input arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [`diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) with [*boolean array indexing*](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) :

```
out = array1[(np.diff(array1, prepend=True) > 1).cumsum() == 1]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

#[10 11 12 13 14 15 16]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse your array and check when the absolute difference is not 1:

```
def remove_noise(arr):
    idx = len(arr) - np.argmax(np.abs(np.diff(np.flip(arr))) != 1) - 1
    return arr[idx:]
```

Usage:

```
>>> remove_noise(array1)
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])

>>> remove_noise(array2)
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
```

Comment: The *hundred k* looks dope, congrats Corralien ;)